# Is there any setting that could allow me to print this overhang without support?

Tags: print-quality, support-structures

I've been asked to print a set of this:
[image]

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2200026

I used Slicer with my default settings for my FLSun printer which includes support and 0.2mm layer height and that rail was printed as whole block with some excess which would allow me to remove the support, but that didn't work because the support simply melted with the top part of the rail.

Tried again with no support and the first layer of the top part of the rail simply felt because there was nothing there to support it.

Is there any configuration that would allow me to print this <s>bridge</s> overhang correctly? Maybe printing the rail diagonally?!

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What orientation are you printing? I would orient it as though it were an ice skate blade  and print without support.  At worst you might have to clean out the "lower" channel slightly after printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a minor correction: the feature you are trying to print is not a *bridge* (which is an unsupported length of filament between two parts of the print) but rather a *overhang* (which is an unsupported length of filament supported only at one end).

The reason why your overhang is impossible to print without support is that slicers create a *shell* first or - in other words - trace the perimeter of the layer you are printing.  This feature, combined with the fact that your overhang is perpendicular to the part it originates from, causes the printer to try to extrude into thin air the perimeter of your rail, like this (the yellow lines are the shell, the red ones the infill):

[image]

In the image above, also the infill is extruded into thin air, but this is actually something that you can change in most slicers (look for "infill pattern orientation" or something similar).

One option you have is to tweak the support parameters to make it unobtrusive and easy to remove, like for example this:

[image]

(The above was done in Cura, with infill pattern "lines", spaced 5mm apart and no support interface or other additional structures).

Since your parts won't be subject to a great deal of mechanical stress another solution could be to change their printing orientation.  In the following example, the *overhangs* do actually become *bridges* and as such should print without problems:

[image]

Just consider it will take considerably longer to print.

Comment: I don't think I could print it without support on my setup (Simplify3D + DeltaRocket). The first thing I'd try is to print it vertically.

Comment: Hey, that's what I said in my comment!  :-)  .   Well explained.